# SFINAE disable constructor if conversion exists from `double` to `T`

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, c++14, sfinae

The following is the minimal meaningful program that I could come up with to reproduce my predicament for this question. The program fails to compile due to a conflict between the constructors of `LinearForm<double>`. To resolve this conflict, I would like to enable `LinearForm<V>::LinearForm(double)` if and only if no conversion exists from `double` to `V`. How can  I do this? (And will it resolve the conflict between the constructors?)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <array>

template<int N>
struct Vector{
    std::array<double,N> coords;

    Vector(std::array<double,N> coords) : coords(coords) {}

    // implicit conversions between scalar and Vector<1>
    template<int Nd = N, std::enable_if_t<Nd==1>>
    Vector(double scalar) : coords(scalar) {}
    template<int Nd = N, std::enable_if_t<Nd==1>>
    operator double() const {return coords[0];}

    double dot(Vector<N> u) const {
        double acc = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
            acc += coords[i]*u.coords[i];
        }
        return acc;
    }

    static Vector<N> zero(){ return Vector<N>(std::array<double,N>{}); }
};

template<typename V> // V is domain element type i.e. LinearForm maps from V to double
struct LinearForm {
    V v;
    LinearForm(V v) : v(v) {}

    //template<typename Vd=V, typename = std::enable_if_t</* WHAT TO PUT IN HERE */>>
    LinearForm(double v) : LinearForm(V::zero())
    {
        if(v != 0){
            throw std::runtime_error("LinearForm cannot be non-zero constant.");
        }
    }
    double operator()(V u){return u.dot(v);}
};

int main()
{
    LinearForm<Vector<2>> lf(Vector<2>({1,2}));
    LinearForm<Vector<2>> zf = 0;

    LinearForm<double> slf = 0;

    auto u = Vector<2>({3,4});
    lf(u); // returns some value
    zf(u); // should return zero for any u

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use [`std::is_convertible`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_convertible/). Then, this will do the work:

```cpp
template <typename Vd=V,
          typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<double, Vd>::value>::type* = nullptr>
LinearForm(double v) : LinearForm(V::zero())
{
    if(v != 0){
        throw std::runtime_error("LinearForm cannot be non-zero constant.");
    }
}
```

To have your code to compile, I needed to add two more things:

```cpp
LinearForm(int value) : v(value) {}
```

and modify

```cpp
template<int Nd = N, std::enable_if_t<Nd==1>>
Vector(double scalar) : coords(scalar) {}
```

to

```cpp
template<int Nd = N>
Vector(double scalar) : coords({scalar}) {}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tENwAcpLegAyeWpgByxgEaZiXSaQAOqBYXVaPUMTQV9/NTo7B2cjNw9OTkVlTFVAhgJmYgJg41MLZJVI2gysgminV3dPRUzs3NCkhTry%2B0q46sSASkVUA2JkDgByKQBme2RDLABqcVGdAgBPb0wAfQJiZkIFOexxAAYAQTGJqcxZ%2BazNxd2D46OCTCNvYUe5nXsCacdbo%2BbiAyqaYANVSRGI4gA7LIjtM4dNmugQCArswbvN0H0XOxSD9RthpmgSOgdqMYfdDvCQWCSBBEcjUeidJiDNjMLjdoTUMSFF1piAuTyIETiCS%2BVDZJCACJ3O5UgD08umeGerDwyEIXNoADd3P46Appm4CAB3TBaBEsYTEaYidDU1Qkd6cX6U%2BGPVXMN7zT7fe1zKXfV1U0GO4gQFlsy1sLJ8gUikkQCUKK1ZKFS8XQ9Ny91PF5ezDvX2Of2jQOOUgIghIkBaZhs1Z4Kjrd4lgMBl344Pw1ArTbg6aR9gQPloWjNWbQ4iYAj9WiC0U7ACs0n24iXMrJ2aOObhQ/OmIIEFD4NbnIMo4NXwlu6pg6x7FtyGQF0Da63sLvcJo4d9eAD77SMqZ5ksBMhyF0N6fl%2BVLMM%2BszgWWC4kuu0j/huABUBgAHQJsuaHrpu5IwZOMrQXe06zsQ85wRIH5unC24UlSzReuqDqnvMeIEgAXu4qAjhK0yUXOHFOlxux0tWDLENc7z7hyXZZtKkGgUx2b0XcHr5t6CzLHWRjnMCnKKiCyqGpiRhbPOKSGfQ0xLCsyrYZg2HTBUWQAGIkEY0xWd4hpUMQqC%2BcCDmoPerLsHc/yAl8HnEN5xC%2BVBDFmdqczEfCCVJUYEB/nG0zavlmaSmRaU5T5x5FYVxXaqV6nkdprznO8jkGUZ6ABsClbtbQzCGVWNZ1g2TYtvM9IgHgCirGOurZHgbLyQ%2B7Igl1%2BLItqbAGIWG0gO1GGvtMtAGKwrDeBs3ZwpVyURitNX8u5bReVVwLInxwUjpB5GpSRTYQNq0xgGAAbTPskFZuRJEEAgwUmkNyIAvQKprO4wXhlIkg3b5LC0LQqBfG4x10AAtB9EVjqx9DYZjqlZV%2BTFUo1aX7tMvbuF6tJdNVF4SiJ1HTDhh4A3T6nSplspHL6Vn2IJO6QxVz2JT57wnuJOiSLc%2BLTKwVDHjSELzJr%2BJJtCSSaypovkdjqsG%2B8xt7NrPFUEdgGS4rDgvcly1RbtBIKLrrsSzu5HMAYRCC0dauGxrkkSqMpDcOmVtpbrEC86Bpn8%2BOCIhecW2GIW5HO%2BndPTKZCgIH0rD2tn0zk9MP62rQiyC%2B7VJ1278tSkMPSsCAQxLkMpCmEM%2BzD6gA86HIci5/0gwIaMnDDwQA/j10PQANYgEu3DYaM%2BzmPsACcozH8f3CQpCR%2BQgAbEIA/cMPo/j6Qk9DMPCggPspCr2PvekDgLAGAiAUAhW8HgdgZAKDCnAZA6owBj5eCoJAx4xAv4QBcGvYeLh7BZEWAPZepA0BGDsgQAA8rQVgBD/6kCwFZUQ7BsF0LwNONIuov60MwAAD1SOHYYr9PjKGYWqFwmxiCLD0FgQhK9iAqhkT0Gg9AmBsA4DwfgghhCiBQDPGQQhFpf0gD0XsxROEk0RAGCQ4EZCcEhJ/FIaQNAQGsA0UwSRrAVFiPEMIfgAh0FcT4iIgRPFVASIUME6QWgBKaA44opRsghI6GE1i9R9B5EECk1oMRQlcB6AoPoAw1F9wHkPEezD37cPMLfEmt9uDTGAPBY%2B2FJDTAgLgQgJBF5JGmHoZ48CbRjE4Hyae1jpAr2wRvUg29uBLmwsfO%2BS5OD7EkLfSQayZlLgfkMJ%2BpAjA704NhfY3BJDmCWSfcwkIkFLlGPfF%2BE8B6f2/r/CZgCQEQCQH0Ag3hw7kEoCQiBUDBCYHwOCQQSjGBWjUbwE0mxvAKK2aUu5b8B6DOmCaQgCBpiVOqbU%2BpjTmnjP/pMhAmBmBYA8COLZOy9kWDmUuSEnBzDn32JwSQ%2BxITcFqWU2h79Hk/z/uvLeZhZm32PpwY%2B%2Bxb77H2EuNZ4rJC8H7kMUYz9ykPOeUS4pQxJCqp5eqgVvcejzX1PkIAA%3D%3D%3D)

Answer (score 1):

```
std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<double, Ty>>* = nullptr>
```

is what you're searching for